# Trigger search using the magnifier icon

Tags: jquery

I want to make a search form so that when the user clicks one time the search input form is toggled, then the user write what to search in the form and then when the user clicks the search icon again the search should be triggered. Then when the user clicks the search icon for the 3rd time the form should toggle or disappear. Right now what happens is when the user clicks the search icon the search input is toggled and when the user press enter the search is toggled.

the current code is this one :

```
$("#search_nav").click(function () {

$(this).siblings('input').toggle();
$search-button.click();
if(event.keyCode === 13){
   priceRange();
}
});
```

Comment: why not use `boolean` change every click, like a switch on/off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.is(":visible")` (https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to determine what to do, along with clearing the content on search, eg:

```js
$("#search_nav").click(function() {

  var inp = $(this).siblings('input');
  if (!inp.is(":visible"))
    return inp.toggle().focus();  // or .show()
    
  var txt = inp.val();
  if (txt === "")
    return inp.toggle(); // or.hide()
    
  // clear input
  inp.val("");
  alert("searching for " + txt);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='searchwrapper'>
  <button id='search_nav'>[Q]</button><!-- Q looks a bit like magnifier icon... -->
  <input id='search' placeholder="search" style='display:none;'>
</div>
```